# CouchDb Query 2 Keys - Email and DateTimeOffset Range

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, couchdb

I will be pushing data that looks something like this. I am making a web API that'll post and query a message history.

```
{
   "sender":"johndoe@gmail.com",
   "timeSent":"2018-12-17T00:00:00-00:00",
   "subject":"Test Message Subject",
   "body":"Test Message Body",
   "recipients":[
      {
         "account":"447",
         "sites":[
            "161",
            "162"
         ]
      }
   ]
},
{
   "sender":"janedoe@gmail.com",
   "timeSent":"2018-12-17T00:00:00-00:00",
   "subject":"Test Message Subject",
   "body":"Test Message Body",
   "recipients":[
      {
         "account":"447",
         "sites":[
            "161",
            "162"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to make a view that will query it whoever the sender was and a date time off set range using the time sent. So will there be two keys?

I want to specify the sender, start and end key of the datetimeoffset.

I am stuck for about 4hrs now looking for solutions.

Do I create the database via code or is it already created in the GUI?

I've tried something like: **FYI This is just another set of data for practicing**

http://localhost:5984/children/_design/name-age/_view/name-age-query?startkey=["sofia", 5]&endkey=["sofia", 11]

using names and age but it seems that there is something wrong.

the documents looks like this

```
{
 "id": "8a6469af31cb8032e49c2e6648000e92",
 "key": "8a6469af31cb8032e49c2e6648000e92",
 "value": {
  "rev": "1-e6d0d4d825cd6c4072316443065c67d7"
 },
 "doc": {
 "_id": "8a6469af31cb8032e49c2e6648000e92",
 "_rev": "1-e6d0d4d825cd6c4072316443065c67d7",
 "first_name": "Sophia",
 "last_name": "Jones",
 "gender": "f",
 "age": 7
}
}
```

This was the mapping in the view:

```
function (doc) {
    emit([doc.first_name, doc.age], [doc.first_name, doc.last_name, doc.age]);
}
```

This is the actual results, why is it empty?

```
{
    "total_rows": 6,
    "offset": 4,
    "rows": []
}
```

Comment: Is this a typo  because I see that you're querying `sofia` when the first_name in the database is `Sophia`.